# gulp lossy image compression does not work

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, node-modules, image-compression

I try to use `gulp-imagemin` module with `imagemin-mozjpeg` plugin to lossely compress image assets. I tried to modelled my gulp pipeline on the `lossy-imagemin` module (here its simple source code: https://github.com/builden/lossy-imagemin/blob/master/lib/lossy-imagemin.js).

So I have a `gulpfile.js` like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant');
var mozjpeg = require('imagemin-mozjpeg');
var lossymin = require('lossymin-imagemin');

gulp.task('imagemin', function() {
    gulp.src('src/img/*')
    .pipe(imagemin({ progressive: true, 
                     use:[pngquant(), 
                     mozjpeg({quality: '70'})],
                     verbose: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('img_imagemin'))
});

gulp.task('lossymin', 
    lossymin('src/img/*','img', 
             { jpgQuality: '70', cache: false },
             function(err) {}
    )
);
```

And the problem is that the `'lossymin'` task based on `lossy-imagemin` does work correctly (that is, it compresses images really well with about 80% reduction), but my custom task `'imagemin'` which is basically the same as the `'lossymin'` task (look at the source code of the `lossy-imagemin'` modules; the link is above) does not work, that is, it almost does not compresses images at all (6.5% reduction).

So the question is: why is it so?

I seriously have no idea, so any help will be much appreciated.

EDIT.
I found a partial answer. For some reason `gulp-imagemin` in version 3.0+ starts to behave differently when joined with `imagemin-mozjpeg` and `imagemin-pngquant`. When I switch to older versions of these 3 modules I get good compression like when using `lossy-imagemin` module.

However it still entirely unclear to me why these new versions behave so strangely.

So summing up, versions:

- `gulp-imagemin 2.4.0`
- `imagemin-mozjpeg 5.1.0`
- `imagemin-pngquant 4.2.2`

works nice and give more than 80% reduction in compression. At the same time versions:

- `gulp-imagemin 3.3.0`
- `imagemin-mozjpeg 6.0.0`
- `imagemin-pngquant 5.0.1`

behave weird and give only 6.5% reduction on the same images and the same settings (quality = 70).

So all of this is very strange.

[I add `node` as tag, since it seems to be related to some weird interactions between node modules]

Comment: If you're using lossy compression on images, there's no need to use lossless compression on top of it...

Comment: What do you mean exactly, by "using lossless compression on top of it"? I think gulp-imagemin combined with mozjpeg-imagemin should give lossy compression. And indeed this is the case for the older version of gulp-imagemin and mozjpeg-imagemin, but not for the newer versions.